# question about z-stabalizer

Tags: error-correction

[image]I'm learning quantum error correction. I also had a hard time understanding the following stabilizer form. I read this paper, which gives two circuits for Z-Stabilizer, I can understand a but I don't know why b can achieve the same effect: use ancilla qubits to control the original state will that change the state of original qubit?

Answer (score 1):

This follows easily from the observation that $$(I\otimes H)CZ(I\otimes H)=CNOT$$ see for instance [this post and the answers within](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12458/show-that-a-cz-gate-can-be-implemented-using-a-cnot-gate-and-hadamard-gates?noredirect=1&lq=1). Then, since $H^2=I$ simply put an $H\cdot H$ in between all the CZ (controlled-$Z$) gates to turn them into CNOTs, so (b) and (a) are equivalent circuits.